# Update Manager doesn't show the latest version for upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I want to upgrade it to 15.04. However, the update manager shows only 12.10. I tried changing its settings -> all new versions and disabling third party softwares, but it only shows 12.10. I have no pending updates on my system. How do i rectify this problem, without doing a fresh install?

Comment: I tried all the solutions in it, except fresh install , which is my criteria here.

Comment: It's probably worth writing an actual answer to this question with the text you've just edited into your question. Then you can accept your own answer, and close the question @user221478

Comment: While I agree that this could very well be solved with the information given by Ravan, that solution is almost *too* comprehensive. I think the OP may have set the upgrade to "For any new version", which naturally would be 12.10. If he would set it to "For long-term support versions" it should then show 14.04. Just my 2 cents. :)

Comment: I tried setting the "For long-term support versions" and it didn't work. I am a she btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's showing it now. Although, I still don't have an exact clue how. I tried miscellaneous methods, like changing my server to main server. Then i incorrectly modified my sources.list file. I rectified it using Arronical's method in Failed to fetch message while upgrading . Then i ran sudo update-manager -p and it showed that option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip versions then, only Ubuntu lts versions can be upgraded from one lts to another, i.e.,

```
Ubuntu 12.04 lts -> Ubuntu 14.04 lts
```

But if you want to upgrade to any other non-lts versions, then you have to upgrade it one version at a time, i.e.,

```
Ubuntu 12.04 lts -> Ubuntu 12.10 -> Ubuntu 13.04 -> Ubuntu 13.10 ...
```

What you can do at the best here (in your case) is that, upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 lts and then to 15.10, i.e.,

```
Ubuntu 12.04 lts -> Ubuntu 14.04 lts -> Ubuntu 15.04 -> Ubuntu 15.10
```

Comment: My problem is that if in settings , i put "notify me of a new version" to "For lts versions" it doesn't show any version to upgrade. If i put "notify me of a new version" to "for all versions", it doesn't show any version to  upgrade to at all. I don't have any problem with progressive updates, but the problem is that the option isnt coming at all.

Comment: the problem in upgrading to 12.10, is that it's no longer supported